# What kind of cloth did Genghis Khan use in his armor?

Tags: military, war, mongol-empire

Genghis Khan the king of the Mongolian Empire used a specific kind of cloth material for his military fatigues. This cloth material worked as an armor and was an advantage for his soldiers to win battles with less human loss.

What kind of cloth did Genghis use in his armor?

Comment: I have no  evidence, but it could be silk. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_armour

Comment: This is the first I've ever heard of this, and textile working doesn't really seem to be in the Mongol Horde's core competencies. Got a reference for it?

Comment: Is there any evidence of this assertions?  Do you have a source?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Mongols wore silk underneath their armor. The benefit of using silk was that if a Mongol warrior was hit with an arrow the silk would not break and they could pull the arrow out by pulling on the silk on each side of the wound and the arrow would come out.

References:

- [Review of Genghis Khan and the Making of the Modern World](http://www.thewriterscoin.com/genghis-khan-and-the-making-of-the-modern-world-%E2%80%94-review/)
- [Mongol War Strategy](http://fourriverscharter.org/projects/Inventions/pages/centralasia_mongolstrategy.htm)
- [Koryo and the Mongols](http://www.koreanhistoryproject.org/Ket/C05/E0506.htm)

Comment: Cute as my above comment may have been, this does appear to be the answer to the question asked. I doubt it worked as reliably as you imply, but for the time I could see where silk might have been the best available equivalent to wearing Kevlar.

Comment: I'd heard this a long time ago, it's good to see this confirmed again.  The ease of removing arrows with silk was something I've seen mentioned again and again in regards to many Asian warrior cultures.